# Are Norwegian advertised salaries net or gross?

Tags: postdocs, salary, norway

Different countries have different ways of giving a salary range, in some countries I have noticed that the job posting explicitly says "estimated net salary". Now I am wondering about academic jobs in Norway, it is never specified in job postings so there must be a social norm I guess.

For example
https://www.jobbnorge.no/en/available-jobs/job/231207/coordinator-of-community-sampling-for-the-biodiversity-genomics-europe-bge-project

According to some online tax calculator website, a gross salary of 650k NOK per year is about 475k net/year. All the post-docs I have seen are around 500k-600k per year but none of them specify if net or gross. The tax rate seems to be around 30%, are these calculation in a good estimate?

Comment: Just guessing here, but if "net" that would probably be stated.

Answer (score 2):

How much taxes you pay usually depends on individual factors (that you do not have to share), therefore the advertised salary is in general gross.

Gross salary depends as well on individual factors, but with respect to individual factors that you *do* have to share at the interview.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Norway in general, but all the adds I have seen from UiO give the gross salary. In addition to online tax calculators (they're usually accurate, you would expect to pay ~25-30% tax with a PhD/postdoc salary), depending on your situation you might also be able to enroll in the PAYE scheme for your first year in Norway (25% flat rate): https://www.skatteetaten.no/en/person/foreign/are-you-intending-to-work-in-norway/tax-deduction-cards/paye/

This most likely depends on specific department and funding source, but from what I've seen at UiO a postdoc typically earns 32-35.000 NOK a month, net. This seems to be in agreement with the add you linked.

Comment: Thank you this is useful.